# Change site URL in all SharePoint Online objects

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

We developed a new Intranet on a o365 SharePoint site collection name Intranet-test and soon will clone the site and rename it intranet. How can we rename all references to intranet-test to intranet in all lists, libraries, and web parts? The tools available to use are the REST API, powershell pnp, SharePoint designer, and Metalogix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use PnP PowerShell Provision engine to clone all the lists,libraries and web parts into the new site "intranet", After provisioning, the list/library/web part url will be automatically changed to the new site url:

[Getting started with the PnP Provisioning Engine and PnP PowerShell](https://www.erwinmcm.com/getting-started-with-the-pnp-provisioning-engine-and-pnp-powershell/)